# Fetching only 1065 rows put of database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have stored my .db file in asstes/databases folder. When I am trying to fetch the data using SQLiteAssetHelper, it is returning cursor with only 1065 n total regardless of my total rows in total. When I checked my db file in Browser for SQLite it found 4068 rows.
Can anybody suggest where I am going wrong.??

[image]

Comment: Maybe you are looking at different `smatcase.db` that's why you assume that you have 4068 rows. If you want to get a fresh copy of your database perform an `adb pull` in `data/data/{package}/databases/smatcase.db`

Comment: No there is only a smartcase.db which I a using.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved when I uninstalled the application and installed again. The first time I ran there were 1065 records. so next time onwards, it was not refreshing the db file or something.